Question about Ridley's peak current mode control model, why the L in small signal model can be seen short-circuit when driving Kf'
I have a question about Ridley's way of deriving Kf' in his PHD paper: Why can the L in the small signal model be seen as a short-circuit? L can only be seen as short-circuit when calculating DC gain, right? We can't see Kf' as only a DC gain, right?



(Above image from: Answer to "Derivation of Feedforward Gains for current mode control in CCM converter" by Verbal Kint, posted on Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange, licensed under CC BY-SA 4.0)

I wrote this PPT some years ago already but, on average, the voltage across an inductance, at steady-state, is 0 V owing to the volt-second balance law.

Hi Verbal, very happy get your reply. I seem to have fallen into a trap, in small signal model, if the <VL(t)> can be ignored, there should not be perturbation of <iL(t)>, right?
